# SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I upgraded my WebApi project from NET6 to NET7. I use EF Core 7 in my project.

I knew that there was a breaking change involving SQL Server and certificates. So I changed my connection string in the project's `appsettings.json` to:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DB": "data source=myserver;initial catalog=mydb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=MyApp;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Encrypt=false;"
}
```

I added `Trusted_Connection`, `TrustServerCertificate` and `Encrypt` to test if the connection will work.

The website was published to IIS (where the ASP.NET Core Runtime 7.0.0 is installed).

However I'm getting the following exception on a GET request:

> SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

And the following on another GET request:

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occurred while processing your request.","status":500,"traceId":"00-f7ac7c853fbfe3ef43a3d8b567fadbdb-a30b994f51839fcb-00"}

The above changes to the above connection string should have fixed this problem. But the problem persists and I don't know that else I can change to get the website to work again.

The SQL Server either has a self-signed certificate or no certificate at all. All I need is to get the code to work with the current setup.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you asking for help with regards to the certificate chain or are you trying to get the code to work with what you have set up? Viva Malta.

Comment: Trying to get the code to work

Comment: `TrustServerCertificate=True` should take care if the server uses self-signed cert. `Encrypt=False` makes the server interaction to _not_ go over ssl/tls - which your server may not be allowing, check that part.

Comment: All communication is over SSL/TLS

Comment: Then why do you have `Encrypt=False`?

Comment: To test which of the settings combination will get the app to work again.

Comment: Is your SQL Server patched with this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe